# Changing size of tappable Button area – contentShape(_:) not working

Tags: ios, swiftui

I'm making a custom tab bar in SwiftUI using `TabView(selection:)` and hiding the default tab in `ContentView`'s `init` (not a good practice, I know).

I have two tab buttons in the tab view, like this:

```
HStack(spacing: 0) {
    Button(action: { selectedTab = .history  }) {
        EmptyView()
    }
    .buttonStyle(TabButtonStyle(systemImage: "rectangle.stack.person.crop", tab: .history, currentTab: selectedTab))
    
    Spacer()
    
    Button(action: { selectedTab = .profile }) {
        EmptyView()
    }
    .buttonStyle(TabButtonStyle(systemImage: "person.crop.circle", tab: .profile, currentTab: selectedTab))
}
.overlay(tapButton)
.padding(.horizontal, 50)
.padding(.vertical, 10)
.padding(.bottom, UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.safeAreaInsets.bottom)
.ignoresSafeArea(.all, edges: .bottom)
```

`tapButton` is a custom tab button overlayed on top, and the paddings are to recreate the dimensions of the default tab bar.

With `TabButtonStyle` (necessary for the custom behaviour where the image switches to its filled alternative when the user is pressing it, not after they release their finger) like this:

```
struct TabButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
    let systemImage: String
    let tab: Tab
    var currentTab: Tab
    
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        return Image(systemName: configuration.isPressed || tab == currentTab ? "\(systemImage).fill" : systemImage)
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
            .frame(width: 25, height: 25)
    }
}
```

Although this works like a charm, the tappable area ends up just being the image, which is too small and finicky for our fingers. The usual way to change this is to add the `contentShape(_:)` modifier – however, when I add it (either to the `TabButtonStyle` or after the Buttons themselves), the button isn't tappable anymore. It doesn't respond to taps, regardless of the Shape that I give in the argument.

Is there something I'm doing wrong here, maybe because of the `EmptyView`? Even if without the `contentShape(_:)` it works perfectly fine? Maybe this is due to the inner workings of `contentShape(_:)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding padding works with Xcode 12.1 / iOS 14.1

```
return Image(systemName: configuration.isPressed || tab == currentTab ? "\(systemImage).fill" : systemImage)
    .resizable()
    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
    .frame(width: 25, height: 25)
    .padding()                      // << here !!
```